# to_categorical() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm writing a short Python program to test tensorflow model, but blocked when I apply one-hot encoding on labels data in 'Mnist'

the error message is `TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

code box

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

def load_processing_mnist(train_ratio, train_batch_size, test_batch_size):
    (train_validation_ds, test_ds), ds_info = tfds.load(name = 'mnist',
                                                        shuffle_files = True,
                                                        as_supervised = True,
                                                        split = ['train', 'test'],
                                                        with_info=True)

    n_train_validation = ds_info.splits['train'].num_examples 
    n_train = int(n_train_validation * train_ratio) 
    n_validation = n_train_validation - n_train  
    
    train_ds = train_validation_ds.take(n_train) 
    remaining_ds = train_validation_ds.skip(n_train) 
    validation_ds = remaining_ds.take(n_validation)

    def normalization(images, labels):
        images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)/255.
        oh_labels = to_categorical(labels)
        #  TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
        return [images, oh_labels]

    train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(1000).map(normalization).batch(train_batch_size)
```

I have 2 question

1. `oh_labels = to_categorical(labels)`
   labels of train data set in 'Mnist'  is not 1 argument?
2. what difference between `tf.one_hot` and  `to_categorical`?

I only studied English just for a few month, maybe my write is not good for read.
So, your point out about words and sentence what I used will be a good chance improve to me.
Thank you for reading, and I would be very grateful if you could give me a good answer.

-- version

Python 3.8.5

numpy : 1.19.2

tensorflow : 2.4.1

Os

window 10

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue myself, unfortunately the to_categorical is not compatible with mapping

To get around this, you can use

```
def normalization(images, labels):
    images = tf.cast(images, tf.float32)/255.
    oh_labels = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), num_classes), dtype=labels.dtype)
    return [images, oh_labels]
```

change 'num_classes' to be the number of classes you want